# Why the printk console_loglevel can be lower than minimum_console_loglevel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, rhel, printk

My `Linux` distro is `RHEL7`, and kernel version is `3.10.0`.

Form the [printk](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt) document, I know **minimum_console_loglevel** definition:

> - minimum_console_loglevel: minimum (highest) value to which
>     console_loglevel can be set

Querying current log level of `printk`:

```
[root@localhost kernel]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
7       4       1       7
```

Modify current console log level:

```
[root@localhost kernel]# echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/printk
[root@localhost kernel]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
0       4       1       7
```

Per my understanding, the **minimum_console_loglevel** is `1`, so modifying **console_loglevel** to `0` should be failed. But from the *cat* output, it seems success.

From `printk.c` code:

```
case SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_LEVEL:
        error = -EINVAL;
        if (len < 1 || len > 8)
            goto out;
        if (len < minimum_console_loglevel)
            len = minimum_console_loglevel;
        console_loglevel = len;
        /* Implicitly re-enable logging to console */
        saved_console_loglevel = -1;
        error = 0;
        break;
```

I also think **console_loglevel** values shouldn't be modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong code. `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` is provided by `kernel/sysctl.c`. The definition for `printk` [looks like this](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sysctl.c?v=3.18#L773):

```
{
    .procname       = "printk",
    .data           = &console_loglevel,
    .maxlen         = 4*sizeof(int),
    .mode           = 0644,
    .proc_handler   = proc_dointvec,
},
```

This defines a file called `printk` which controls an int array of 4 elements. Crucially, `proc_dointvec`, the handler function, is a generic function that operates on an array of integers, and *it doesn't validate its arguments*.

As root, you can therefore write whatever garbage numbers you want to `/proc/sys/kernel/printk` and the kernel will happily accept them. Demo:

```
root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/kernel# echo '-989897 42 -2147483648 0' > printk
root@ubuntu:/proc/sys/kernel# cat printk
-989897 42  -18446744071562067968   0
```

(That 3rd one is actually an amusing and *probably* harmless bug I've just discovered...)

From [`printk.h`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/printk.h?v=3.18#L47) you can see that the four log level parameters are derived straight from this four-element array:

```
extern int console_printk[];

#define console_loglevel (console_printk[0])
#define default_message_loglevel (console_printk[1])
#define minimum_console_loglevel (console_printk[2])
#define default_console_loglevel (console_printk[3])
```

---

So, then, what does the code you posted do then? It implements the `syslog` syscall, as noted by the name of the function (`do_syslog`). As noted by [the man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syslog.2.html):

```
   SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_LEVEL (8)
          The call sets console_loglevel to the value given in len,
          which must be an integer between 1 and 8 (inclusive).  The
          kernel silently enforces a minimum value of
          minimum_console_loglevel for len.  See the log level section
          for details.  The bufp argument is ignored.
```

We can see that the `syslog` system call also lets you set the console log level, but it actually checks that the values are valid. Let's test with a simple test program (note that glibc calls the function `klogctl` instead of `syslog`, since the user-space `syslog` function does something else):

```
#include <sys/klog.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_LEVEL 8

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(klogctl(SYSLOG_ACTION_CONSOLE_LEVEL, NULL, atoi(argv[1])) < 0) {
        perror("klogctl");
    } else {
        printf("klogctl succeeded\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Run it (after resetting `printk` back to `7 4 1 7`):

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp# ./test 1 ; cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
klogctl succeeded
1   4   1   7
root@ubuntu:/tmp# ./test 0 ; cat /proc/sys/kernel/printk
klogctl: Invalid argument
1   4   1   7
```

and so you can see that `syslog` (called via `klogctl`) does actually check the validity of your parameters.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer! Another question. Per my understanding, since `proc_dointve` doesn't do integer check, we can bypass **minimum_console_loglevel**, right? If it is right, should it be considered as a bug? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it could be considered a bug, but I don't think there's a big focus on validating the sysctl files. (You could try submitting a bug report...)